# how to alter the height of a textblock

Tags: wpf, xaml

The width of the background of a textblock that surrounds the text is very narrow.  However, the top and bottom is very large.  How do I shrink this space down?  I can't do it by setting the height, and I can't attach a negative padding to it.

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <TextBlock  FontSize="200"                                 
                    FontWeight="Bold"
                    Background="Black"
                    Foreground="White"  
                    Text="bla bla"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Oh crap.  I figured this would be simple.  Guess not...

Comment: You're going to want to adjust the [LineStackingStrategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock.linestackingstrategy?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [LineHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock.lineheight?view=netframework-4.7.2) dependency properties of `TextBlock` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Height` of the element to reduce the space at the bottom, you can combine `TextWrapping`, `LineHeight` and `LineStackingStrategy` to adjust the space at the top of the element:

```
<Grid>    
    <TextBlock  FontSize="200"                                 
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Background="Black"
            Foreground="White"  
            Text="bla bla"
            Padding="0"
            Margin="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
            LineHeight="200" 
            Height="180">
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

The property you need to set is LineHeight, combined with LineStackingStrategy = "BlockLineHeight"

```
<TextBlock FontSize="72" 
    Background="Black" 
    Foreground="White" 
    FontWeight="Bold" 
    Text="Hello World" 
    LineHeight="72" 
    LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" />
```